# Permissions required to upload to Azure Container

Tags: azure

I am trying to give an outside user permission to upload a large file to a container within an Azure data storage account.  If I view the overall permissions of the user across the resource group, it looks as follows:

[image]

They're saying they can't get access and they need Contributor permissions assigned on the Subscription and the Resource Group too.  In my inexperienced mind that indicates they'll have visibility of all the resources.  Are they correct or should the permissions I assigned be sufficient?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The role you're looking for is [`Storage Blob Data Contributor`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/role-based-access-control/built-in-roles#storage-blob-data-contributor) which would give the user permissions to read, write, and delete Azure Storage containers and blobs. You can assign this role to a user on a specific blob container.

Other option for you would be to create a `Shared Access Signature` with just `Write` permission and proper expiry date for a blob container. They can use that to upload a file in that blob container.

Yet another option is to use `Azure Data Share` service. You can read more about how you can receive files using this service here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-share/subscribe-to-data-share.

Comment: Thank you, I've updated the role and awaiting his response.  Am I correct in suspecting his request for Subscription and Resource Group access was an over-reach?

Comment: `Am I correct in suspecting his request for Subscription and Resource Group access was an over-reach?` - Absolutely yes. You would have given the use way more permissions than needed to just upload a blob.